# Verilog megawizard RAM not read

Tags: verilog, ram, quartus-ii

I used Quartus II Magawizard to ask for a two port RAM(one read and one write). The addresses are correct but the data out is always z. Can some one help me with this problem? I have stuck here for a whole day...

I instantiate and connect the RAM as following:

```
 RAM0 ra(
    .clock(clk),
    .rdaddress(raddr_a),
    .wraddress(waddr_a),
    .wren(we_a),
    .q(q_a),
    .data(data_a));
```

and modelsim the RAM:
[image: wave form for RAM ra]

Comment: It should still show at least undefined, not z. Do you get any compilation warnings from Modelsim?

Comment: Quartis also generates a black box file (..._bb.v), make sure you're not simulating that one.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much! I connected the output port q to a port with different width... that is the problem. I should never ignore any warnings! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the poster:

> Finally(maybe temporarily) solve this problem.
>
> Tips: New a modelsim project instead of vsim files directly. Look at
>   all the warnings, see whether port width mismatch. Do not include
>   _bb.v file in the work library or you will get high-z output. Add library if you use third-party src or magawizard.
>
> Thanks to apalopohapa!

From the comments:

> It should still show at least undefined, not z. Do you get any
>   compilation warnings from Modelsim? –  apalopohapa
>
> Quartus also generates a black box file (..._bb.v), make sure you're not simulating that one. –  apalopohapa
>
> Problem solved! Thank you very much! I connected the output port q to a port with different width... that is the problem. I should
>   never ignore any warnings! Thank you! –  SH1991

Comment: Thanks for reply! According to the auto-generated RAM.v file, the two ports are write port(wraddress, data) and read address(rdaddress, q), and rden signal is missing...    `module RAM1 (
 clock,
 data,
 rdaddress,
 wraddress,
 wren,
 q);`

Comment: Perhaps it is a single port ram.  Try de-asserting wren and see if q starts showing data.

Comment: I tried to disable wren after several clk, still no q... May be the data is not write into ram successfully?

Comment: @SH1991 It should still show at least undefined, not z.  Do you get any compilation warnings from Modelsim?

Answer (score 0):

Finally(maybe temporarily) solve this problem.

Tips: 
New a modelsim project instead of vsim files directly.
Look at all the warnings, see whether port width mismatch. 
Do not include _bb.v file in the work library or you will get high-z output. 
Add library if you use third-party src or magawizard.

Thanks to apalopohapa!